# Nginx не раздает статику

Tags: django, nginx

Пытаюсь завести django на nginx по вот этой инструкции:
https://habr.com/post/226419/

Дошел до шага, где нужно раздать статику, но статические файлы не открываются.

Общий конфиг nginx не трогал. Создал свой по инстукции. Его содержимое такое:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # взаимодействие с uwsgi через Unix-сокет (мы воспользуемся этим вариантом позже) 
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # взаимодействие с uwsgi через веб-порт 
}

# конфигурация веб-сервера
server {
    # порт, который будет слушать веб-сервер в ожидании запросов от пользователй
    listen      8000;
    # доменное имя
    server_name     тут_адрес_моего_сайта; # замените на собственный домен или IP адрес
    charset     utf-8;

    # максимальный размер загружаемых на сервер данных
    client_max_body_size 75M;  

    # обслуживание медиа файлов и статики
    location /media  {
        alias /home/kkomissarov/marketing-blog/project/media;  # расположение медиафайлов (при необходимости измените)
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/kkomissarov/marketing-blog/project/static;  # расположение статики (при необходимости измените)

    }

    # Остальные запросы перенаправляются в Django приложение
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/kkomissarov/marketing-blog/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

Затем создал симлинк на этот конфиг в папке /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. Перезапустил сервер командой

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

По основному адресу запускается приветственное сообщение nginx. Папка, указанная в в конфиге для статики и для медиа существует. Создана с помощью collectstatic от джанго, но я думаю это вообще не имеет значения. Ощущение, что мой конфиг вообще ни на что не влияет и не учитвается. Как проверить, что он заинклудился?

Comment: как обычно: смотрите логи.

Comment: А динамика при этом работает?